# What could two lower bounds on media queries mean?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

As a programmer who has to know a bit of design I'm delighted that CSS `grid` finally appeal to my sense of what design should be: concise and logical.

But [authoritative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas) sources write:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 700px) { ... }
```

I would understand setting a lower bound and an upper bound

```
@media (min-width: 500px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 500px) { ... }
```

for a design feature.

Better yet, and since a developer is entitled (/required) to be pedantic, I would be more comfortable with

```
@media (min-width: 500px) { ... }
@media (max-width: 499px) { ... }
```

knowing that we are dealing with integers, not floats (but regardless, is min equivalent to `>=` or `>`?)

My squabble is with the first (min: 500; min: 700). How can that ever make sense? And what does it mean if it does? Does the order of appearance of media queries matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules in the first media query apply if the width is at least 500px.

The rules in the second media query apply if the width is at least 700px.

Since it can't be 700 without also being at least 500, if the rules in the second media query apply then so do the ones in the first.

Multiple conflicting rules are applied according to [the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) **exactly** as if media queries were not involved.

> Does the order of appearance of media queries matter?

Yes, as per the cascade: "Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins."

---

CSS is designed so that you can build your styles from the general to the specific, overriding earlier rules as you go.

Providing default rules, then layering additional ones if the window is wider, and then layering even more if it is very wide is a standard approach.

Trying to build completely different stylesheets for different viewport sizes leads to duplication and makes maintenance harder.

Comment: I see. So instead of one normally writing in a program `if(cond_A) then X elseif(cond_B) then Y else Z`, in CSS design one would write `Z (cond_B) Y (cond_A) X`. Is that right?

Comment: Also, do cascades allow for partial overrides? I mean: after writing `(min-width: 500px) { .wrapper { display: grid; grid-template-areas: ".." ".."; } }` it's sufficient to override with `(min-width: 800px) { .wrapper { grid-template-areas: ".." ".."; } }` without specifying the `display: grid;` again. Is that right?

Comment: Only the rules that are duplicated matter. If you don't write a rule to change a property, it won't override a previous rule that applies to that property.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with those query parameters.

```
@media (min-width: 500px) { } means...
```

If the screen width is equal to or greater than 500px then, let's say, `background-color: orange`.

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { } means...
```

If the screen width is equal to or greater than 700px then, let's say, `background-color: lightgreen`.

The order of the CSS rules does matter, per the rules of the cascade.

Use my demo below for illustrations. Switch the order of the rules for a better understanding of the importance of source order.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzr8a12L/1/)

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
}

section {
  background-color: aqua;
}

section:first-child::after {
  content: "screen width < 500px"
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  section {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  section:first-child::after {
    content: "screen width >= 500px"
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  section {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  section:first-child::after {
    content: "screen width >= 700px"
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  section {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  section:first-child::after {
    content: "screen width >= 900px"
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  article {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

Comment: So the meaning of  `@media (min-width: 500px) { background-color: orange; } @media (min-width: 700px) { background-color: lightgreen; }` is different from `@media (min-width: 700px) { background-color: lightgreen; } @media (min-width: 500px) { background-color: orange; }`(reversed the order of two otherwise identical queries). Is that right?

Comment: The order in which the rules appear in the code does matter, per the rules of the cascade. Use the fiddle I posted in my answer and change the order of rules. All selectors are equal weight (specificity). You'll see the difference.